I am developing a community page using Next.js and Socket. How can I use socket to support sending and receiving images, videos, audio, and documents
i have implemented the functionality of the send image like this using socket.io here is my code block of that.
 socket.on("send-image", async (data) => {
    const { image, room } = data;

    try {
      const savedImage = await prisma.image.create({
        data: {
          imageUrl: image,
          room: room,
        },
      });

      io.to(room).emit("new-image", {
        type: "image",
        image: savedImage.imageUrl, // Send the saved image URL
      });

      //socket.to(room).emit('receive-message', { type: 'image', image: savedImage.imageUrl });
      console.log(`Only Image saved and emitted to room ${room}`);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error saving image to database:", error);
    }
  });

in frontend i have implemented following function to handle it is working fine
const handleImageUpload = () => {
        if (image) {
            const reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onloadend = () => {
                const base64String = reader.result as string; // Convert to string
                socket.emit("send-image", { type: 'image', image: base64String, room });
                setImage(null);
            };
            reader.readAsDataURL(image); // Convert image to base64
        }
    };

    const base64ToBlobUrl = (base64: string) => {
        const byteCharacters = atob(base64.split(',')[1]);
        const byteNumbers = new Uint8Array(byteCharacters.length);
        for (let i = 0; i < byteCharacters.length; i++) {
            byteNumbers[i] = byteCharacters.charCodeAt(i);
        }
        const blob = new Blob([byteNumbers], { type: 'image/png' });
        return URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    };

but now i have implemented same kind of functions for the video and document in socket.io
 // Socket event listener for sending a video message
  socket.on("send-video", async (data) => {
    const { videoUrl, room } = data;

    try {
      // Save the video URL to your database using Prisma
      const savedVideo = await prisma.video.create({
        data: {
          videoUrl: videoUrl,
          room: room,
        },
      });

      // Emit the new video message to all clients in the room
      io.to(room).emit("new-video", {
        type: "video",
        videoUrl: savedVideo.videoUrl, // Send the saved video URL
      });

      console.log(`Only Video saved and emitted to room ${room}`);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error saving video to database:", error);
    }
  });

  socket.on("send-document", async (data) => {
    const { documentUrl, room } = data;

    try {
      // Save the document URL to your database using Prisma
      const savedDocument = await prisma.document.create({
        data: {
          documentUrl: documentUrl,
          room: room,
        },
      });

      // Emit the new document message to all clients in the room
      io.to(room).emit("new-document", {
        type: "document",
        documentUrl: savedDocument.documentUrl, // Send the saved document URL
      });

      console.log(`Only Document saved and emitted to room ${room}`);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error saving document to database:", error);
    }
  });

what changes now i have to make from frontend to implement the these two functions also is there any problem with conversion of base64
